# Should constant values be in SHOUT_CASE when there is language support for them?

Tags: javascript, const

Referring primarily to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), it suggests that values which are constant in JavaScript (using the keyword `const`) should be named in `SHOUT_CASE`. I'm of the opinion though that mutability is much more important (and rare) than immutability, at least in JavaScript, and that having so many variables put in `SHOUT_CASE` would actually harm readability, rather than aid it, and dilute the meaningfulness of the convention itself.

Now, I understand that `SHOUT_CASE` for constants is useful in languages that do not have inherent support for constant values built into the runtime - for example, ES5 javascript, where you had `var` and nothing else. But with language-level support for const values, is there much use for this convention any more?

At runtime, any identifier created using the keyword `const` cannot be re-used or re-assigned to. This isn't strictly const correctness in the C/C++ sense, but for primitives it is fine. For objects, you'd have to use `Object.freeze` to get const-correctness. JavaScript is far from the only language to do this, of course. Fields are commonly `readonly` (C#) or `final` (Java) [citation needed].

What benefits would having things labelled in `SHOUT_CASE` present in a language that already has `const` support built into the syntax?

Comment: Using SHOUT_CASE was a convention that I learned from C++. This may simply be the perpetuation of that convention, however applicable it is to JavaScript.

Comment: It depends on the language and the culture surrounding it. In functional languages, all values are by default constant, so naming  them all in shout-case would indeed impede readability. For example in Scala one would write `val num_files = 5`, not `val NUM_FILES = 5`, because `val` means the reference can't be changed. Since JavaScript is usually written in an imperative style, non-constant variables are the norm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main benefit of using SHOUT_CASE for constants is to easily know when reading code when a particular value is not expected to change without having to look for the definition, or worse, having to search for every reference to that variable to see if its value changes.

Comment: I can understand this, but at the very least I work under the assumption that everything is immutable (for some values of immutable - objects still aren't unless you `Object.freeze`) unless specified otherwise - i.e, I default to using `const` instead of `let` in my code. Is this such a rare thing?

Comment: I personally have not run into many uses of defined constants in Javascript, but YMMV. Most readability guidelines are just that; guidelines. If something makes your code harder to read, then feel free to use a different standard. I often find internal consistency is much more valuable than any single guideline.

Comment: @DanPantry: `Is this such a rare thing?`  -- It is.  Most Javascript code is not written with "immutability by default" in mind.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would argue that a lot of ES2015 is. But I would also argue that that has only been in effect in the past year or so, so it's a poor argument to make.

Answer (score 0):

Given that SHOUT_CASE is a human convention that can't be dependably parsed, no, it shouldn't be used for languages that already allow defining immutables. It's redundant; everything redundant should be removed mercilessly so that learning the language is as simple as possible for future generations.

In general, programming languages should codify as many human universally useful conventions/classifications/taxonomies as they can. Our program editors/readers should be doing the job of making the program clear for us, as much as possible. For instance, using PascalCase for classes to distinguish instances from their camelCase classes/constructor functions should instead be replaced by editors that render those two distinct kinds of values differently. The next paragraph I write will be visually separated by an empty line. I don't have to write a `\n` character and you don't have to visually parse it. I don't have to write a bunch of empty " " space characters to visually separate anything. The browser (and 99.9% of other programs that deal with text) is turning that meaningful/semantic information (the newline character) and rendering it in an intuitive, clear, simple way. Markdown will actually turn this paragraph into a `<p>` tag, which has a specific meaning: "a paragraph of text" - a set of sentences discussing related ideas. Now, Firefox can render this page into a "comfortable reading" mode, and it will include this paragraph, on the assumption that paragraphs represent meaningful content. Screen-readers for the blind can read this text aloud, knowing it's not merely visual UI code. That's how all code editing should work, because code should be marked up with structure and meaning; it's not just text.

Human conventions should be used only where machines *can't* help us.